# Is there a way to save a PySpark dataframe to ARFF format?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I created a dataframe ready and transformed it with `VectorAssembler` to be used with the `ML` lib:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.classification import DecisionTreeClassifier

target_index = StringIndexer(inputCol="target", outputCol="target_idx").fit(df)
assembler = VectorAssembler(
inputCols=[
    x for x in df.columns if x not in ['target', 'ident_1', 'id_l', 'target_idx']
    ],
outputCol='features'
)

cl = DecisionTreeClassifier(labelCol='target_idx', featuresCol='features')
pipe = Pipeline(stages=[target_index, assembler, cl])
model = pipe.fit(df_train)
df_transformed = model.stages[1]
```

and now I want to write the transformed dataset to an `ARFF` file.Is there a way to write a PySpark dataframe already converted by `VectorAssembler` to the `ARFF` format?